# Exiting an iteration in jmeter if the matching Regular Exp condition is not satisfied

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

Could you please guide me how to add a condition to exit the current test iteration and proceed with the next set of iteration  if the Regular expression value  captured in a transaction is 'NotFound'/ ''Null'

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) after the request where you have this Regular Expression Extractor.
2. Use the following expression as Condition (assumes [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3)):

   ```
   ${__jexl3("${foo}" == "NotFound",)}
   ```
3. Add [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler as a child of the If Controller and set "Action" to `Start Next Thread Loop`

   [image: JMeter Test Action Start Next Loop]